# How can I loop through a SQL table and add a unique ID to rows based on a combination of fields?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table and I need to create a unique ID for rows every time I import more data. I want to create a unique ID when there are new combinations of four fields. The Unique ID should look like the example below. What I am struggling to figure out is when a fourth row of data comes in how can I tell SQL to look at the Max Unique ID and spit out a Unique ID = 'asm_0003' if the 4th row is unique from the first 3?

| Member ID | Code | Date | File | Unique ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | I10 | 3/1/21 | file1.txt | asm_0001 |
| 123 | I10 | 3/1/21 | file1.txt | asm_0001 |
| 123 | B12 | 1/1/21 | file1.txt | asm_0002 |

Comment: With a lot of trouble.  Just use an integer `identity`/`auto_increment`/`serial` column (depending on your database)  and call it a day.

Comment: I dont think this will get me to my solution because there are duplicate rows (see example above). I'm using a Dense_Rank() to assign the Unique ID, but the issue is if a new UNIQUE record comes in the dense_rank() does not assign a Unique ID starting at the max+1 of the unique IDs currently in the table. So, a new unique row should have the unique_id = 'asm_0003'

Comment: @Zfieden . . . In that case, you have a problem with your data model.  Why would you want rows that are exact duplicates of each other?

Comment: They arent...each row is distinct but I have duplicates of the 4 fields that make a unique ID. The ID is based on the 4 fields above (member ID, Code, Date, File).